# How to add library headers to common scope

Tags: c, cmake, project-structure

I have following project structure:

```
Project
|-include
| |-somedir
| | |-someheader.h
|-src
| |-somedir
| | |-somesource.c
| | |-CMakeLists.txt
| |-main.c
| |-CMakeLists.txt
|-lib
| |-somelib
| | |-include
| | | |-somelibheader.h
| | |-src
| | | |-somelibsource.c
| | | |-CMakeLists.txt
| | |-CMakeLists.txt
| |-CMakeLists.txt
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

---

**Project/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

project(Project)

list(APPEND INCLUDES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include) # Contains all headers will be add to target

set(LIBRARIES_ROOT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(SOURCES_ROOT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

add_subdirectory(${LIBRARIES_ROOT})
add_subdirectory(${SOURCES_ROOT})
```

**Project/src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${INCLUDES}) # adding headers
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBRARIES}) # linking libraries

add_subdirectory(somedir)
```

**Project/src/somedir/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE somesource.c)
```

**Project/lib/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_subdirectory(somelib)
```

**Project/lib/somelib/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(somelib)
target_include_directories(somelib PRIVATE include)

list(APPEND INCLUDES include) # Adding lib headers to be included to target
list(APPEND LIBRARIES somelib) # Adding lib to be linked to target

add_subdirectory(src)
```

**Project/lib/somelib/src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
target_sources(somelib PRIVATE somelibsource.c)
```

---

In main.c project headers are able to be included, like `#include <somedir/someheader.h>`, but library header doesn't. It requires relative to main.c path, like `#include "../lib/somelib/include/somelibheader.h"`. How to fix it and add library headers to common scope?

Comment: You'd need to add something like `-Ilib/somelib/include` to the command line to be able to use `#include "somelibheader.h"` (or angle brackets if you prefer).  Unless you put the header in a directory `somelib`, you wouldn't be able to write `#include <somelib/somelibheader.h` (or double quotes if you prefer).  That header might be in `lib/somelib/include/somelib` or it might be in `lib/somelib` directly — or you could rename `somelib/include` to `somelib/somelib`.  What you add to the compiler command line depends on which option you choose.

Comment: Why do you need that many CMakeLists.txt files? Can't you use just one CMakeLists.txt? Or is there some specific requirement for such a structure?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it's my mistake. Of course, path is like `lib/somelib/include/somelib`.

Comment: But `-I` option didn't help. Still only relative path works.

Comment: @kiner_shah Rather this is paying tribute to highlevel languages project structure.

Comment: @ReyMagos: Your current **layout** of files (`lib/somelib/include/somelibheader.h`) allows to `#include <somelibheader.h>` (with proper include directory), but it doesn't allow `#include <somelib/somelibheader.h>`. For the latter, you need layout like ``lib/somelib/include/somelib/somelibheader.h``, that is `somelibheader.h` header should be **actually located** in the `somelib` directory.

Comment: Perhaps, my explanation was wrong. It's good if `#include <somelibheader.h>` will work. But it isn't. I understand how works including system. The question is why headers from `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include` including correctly, but from `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/somelib/include` it requires relative path.